# How can we change the text colour of 'Marks' from Material UI?

Tags: material-ui

I am able to change all the color for FormControl, Slider, etc. But one thing I can't find a way to change is the label colour or text colour of the "Marks" of the Slider. Would appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override Material-UI private style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66940755/override-material-ui-private-style)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create style for the marks like

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  ....
  mark: {
    color: "red"
  }
}));
```

then overwrite `markLabel` Global class using  `classes` property of the component like

```
<Slider
        defaultValue={80}
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        aria-labelledby="discrete-slider-always"
        step={10}
        marks={marks}
        valueLabelDisplay="on"
        classes={{ markLabel: classes.mark }}
      />
```

for more customization, you can overwrite all CSS classes which is mention in this doc https://material-ui.com/api/slider/ using `classes` property

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nmzqd5?file=demo.js